# BibTeX style always uses ampersand regardless of choice in makebst

Tags: bibtex, natbib, harvard-style, custom-bib

I've now twice generated a `bst` file using `makebst`. Regardless of my choice when asked whether to use "and" or "&" for 3+ authors in the reference list, the style always uses "&". I would very much prefer "and" to be spelled out. Any idea how to fix this? I am using `harvard`, not `natbib`, but could be persuaded to change.

What initially led me to generate a new style was that kluwer.bst which I was previously using somehow didn't use "et al." for in-text citations (again for sources with 3+ authors) when the publication type is *tech report* but instead put all names into the citation, while it works fine for articles. A remedy for that would also be helpful.

I've looked into the `.bst` files, but I have really no idea what to change. Any help or hints towards a solution would be greatly appreciated as I really have to finish this article.

Comment: what do the author fields in the bib file look like?

Comment: doesnt really matter, I've tried different versions. I thought that was the reason at first because it was formatted like "first name last name and first name last name and ..." but even after I changed it to "last name, first name and ..." (which is what the author field is usually formatted like) it still lists all names instead of putting et al. for articles it also doesn't really matter how the author field is formatted, both versions work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `harvard` package defines a command `\harvardand` which, depending on the style, is set to '&'.  This can be changed to 'and' with:

```
\renewcommand*{\harvardand}{and}
```

Comment: I have since changed to natbib, but this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Search in the generated `bst` file for the  `FUNCTION {bbl.and}` it should be:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}
```

Comment: It actually is. Problem seems to be with the harvard package somehow, Ive just redone it using natbib and it seems to work. Maybe a fix for the second problem, getting kluwer.bst to use et al. for in-text citations of tech reports would be better.

Comment: for  the et al is a `FUNCTION {bbl.etal}`  What does it define?

Comment: The function does not appear in the file. You can find the file under the following link.

http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/kluwer.bst

Comment: kluwer expect for et. al. entries like "Donald Duck and others", which then is converted to "Donald Duck et al." That is defined in the `Function format.names`.

Comment: that is a bit strange, because none of the entries in my bib file looks like that. they look normal, just as described in the comment to my original post. I really dont get why it also works fine for articles.